# Azure Data Factory - Insert Sql Row for Each File Found

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need a data factory that will:

- check an Azure blob container for csv files
- for each csv file

  - insert a row into an Azure Sql table, giving filename as a column value

There's just a single csv file in the blob container and this file contains five rows.

So far I have the following actions:

[image: top-level]

Within the for-each action I have a copy action. I did give this a source of a dynamic dataset which had a filename set as a parameter from @Item().name. However, as a result 5 rows were inserted into the target table whereas I was expecting just one.

The for-each loop executes just once but I don't know to use a data source that is variable(s) holding the filename and timestamp?

Comment: COPY will copy the contents, not the metadata. You already have the blob name with @item().name - I would create a Stored Procedure that accepts the file name as a parameter and call that inside the foreach activity instead of COPY.

Comment: Add a data flow to your pipeline. For the Source, point to your blob container. Enable sampling on the source transformation and set the row limit to 1. Enter a column name, i.e. 'myfilename' for "Column to store file name". Last, add a Sink which is your SQL table. Map the 'myfilename' column. That will store each file name as a single row from your container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are headed in the right direction, but within the For each you just need a Stored Procedure Activity that will insert the FileName (and whatever other metadata you have available) into Azure DB Table.

Like this:
[image: ADF Pipeline Example]

Here is an example of the stored procedure in the DB:

```
CREATE Procedure Log.PopulateFileLog (@FileName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO Log.CvsRxFileLog
select
@FileName as FileName,
getdate() as ETL_Timestamp
```

**EDIT:**
You could also execute the insert directly with a Lookup Activity within the For Each like so:
[image: Lookup Activity within For Each]

**EDIT 2**
This will show how to do it without a for each
NOTE: This is the most cost effective method, especially when dealing with hundred or thousands of files on a recurring basis!!!

**1st, Copy the output Json Array from your lookup/get metadata activity using a Copy Data activity with a Source of Azure SQLDB and Sink of Blob Storage CSV file**

-------SOURCE:
[image: SOURCE of Copy Data Azure DB to Blob]

-------SINK:
[image: SINK of Copy Data Azure DB to Blob]

**2nd, Create another Copy Data Activity with a Source of Blob Storage Json file, and a Sink of Azure SQLDB**

---------SOURCE:

[image: Source of Copy Data Blob to Azure DB]

---------SINK:

[image: Sink of Copy Data Blob to Azure DB]

---------MAPPING:

[image: Mapping of Copy Data Blob to Azure DB]

In essence, you save the entire json Output to a file in Blob, you then copy that file using a json file type to azure db. This way you have 3 activities to run even if you are trying to insert from a dataset that has 500 items in it.

Comment: Many thanks for another detailed answer Trent. However, I'd rather avoid the use of a stored proc if possible because that's more source code to manage. I'm very new to Data Factory but I really like the easy integration with DevOps git repos, and release pipelines. If I add a stored proc then I have to consider how that will get deployed and promoted through dev, test, prod etc. I will investigate a solution using a Data Flow as suggested by @Mark Kromer but failing that I'll fall back to a stored proc.

Comment: Well spinning up a Spark Cluster to insert a single row seems a bit excessive, but it certainly is doable. You could also have no Stored Procedure in the DB and just execute it as a direct insert query via a Lookup. I will edit the answer to reflect this option.

Comment: I should have also mentioned there is a way to do what you want without a For Each, I have developed this method when I needed to iterate over hundreds of files, but didn't want to run 300 activities in the For each (as you pay $1 per 1000 activities when using AutoResolveIR, $1.50/1000 if using Self-Hosted IR *Last time I looked at prices) I will edit my answer to include this more efficient method without a For Each

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is always more than one way to do things, but I don't think you need a For Each activity for this task.  Activities like *Lookup*, *Get Metadata* and *Filter* output their results as JSON which can be passed around.  This JSON can contain one or many items and can be passed to a *Stored Procedure*.  An example pattern:

[image: ADF pattern]

This is the sort of ELT pattern common with early ADF gen 2 (prior to Mapping Data Flows) which makes use of resources already in use in your architecture.  You should remember that you are charged by the activity executions in ADF (eg multiple iteration in an unnecessary For Each loop) and that generally compute in Azure is expensive and storage is cheap, so think about this when implementing patterns in ADF.  If you build the pattern above you have two types of compute: the compute behind your Azure SQL DB and the Azure Integration Runtime, so two types of compute.  If you add a Data Flow to that, you will have a third type of compute operating concurrently to the other two, so personally I only add these under certain conditions.

An example implementation of the above pattern:

[image: ADF implementation]

Note the expression I am passing into my example logging proc:

```
@string(activity('Filter1').output.Value)
```

Data Flows is perfectly fine if you want a low-code approach and do not have compute resource already available to do this processing.  In your case you already have an Azure SQL DB which is quite capable with JSON processing, eg via the OPENJSON, JSON_VALUE and JSON_QUERY functions.

You mention not wanting to deploy additional code which I understand, but then where did your original SQL table come from?  If you are absolutely against deploying additional code, you could simply call the `sp_executesql` stored proc via the *Stored Proc* activity, use a dynamic SQL statement which inserts your record, something like this:

```
@concat( 'INSERT INTO dbo.myLog ( logRecord ) SELECT ''', activity('Filter1').output, ''' ')
```

Shred the JSON either in your stored proc or later, eg

```
SELECT y.[key] AS name, y.[value] AS [fileName]
FROM dbo.myLog
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( logRecord ) x
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( x.[value] ) y
WHERE logId = 16
   AND y.[key] = 'name';
```

Comment: Another great answer - seems the ADF community is a goldmine! In answer to your question "where did your original SQL table come from?", it gets deployed via entity framework core migrations